# Get text from activeX textbox (VBA, powerpoint)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have an activeX textbox in my PowerPoint presentation. During my presentation, I want to write a letter there. Afterward, I want to press a button which opens a messagebox with the letter from the textbox. Currently, my code is the following, but it doesn't work:

```
MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).OLEObjects("tb1").Object.Text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following instead...

```
MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(SlideIndex).Shapes("tb1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
```